# bat to replace text from text file1 to file2 (relative search)

Tags: batch-file, full-text-search, substr

textfile1 is source and textfile2 is target

Example textfile1.txt:

```
  server1.net 2100 /l /n /k port:2000,server2.net 2100 /l /n /k port:20000
```

textfile2.txt:

```
  server3.net 2000 /l /k port:xxxx,server4.net 2000 /l /k port:yyyyy
```

I need to find "port:" characters in textfile1.txt and subst the port number (n character after "port:" characteres), in textfile2.txt

Note: portnumber is variable number in textfile1, but text: "port:" is fixed.
Thanks

Basically I need to put the same port numbers in textfile1 and textfile2

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you want to do this task with batch - it would be much simpler using another scripting language like VBScript, JScript, or perhaps PowerShell.

But here is a native batch solution. My solution makes no assumption as to the order of the options in each command. It allows for any number of options both before and after `/port:nnnn`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::read the line from textfile1
set "str="
<"textfile1.txt" set /p "str="
if not defined str exit /b

::enclose each command in quotes
set "str="!str:,=","!""

::extract the port from each command into an array
set /a n=0
for %%A in (!str!) do (
  set "cmd=%%~A"
  set /a n+=1
  for /f %%B in ("!cmd:*port:=!") do set "port!n!=%%B"
)

::read the line from textfile2
set "str="
<"textfile2.txt" set /p "str="
if not defined str exit /b

::enclose each command in quotes
set "str="!str:,=","!""

::process each command
set /a n=0
set "ln="
for %%A in (!str!) do (
  set "cmd=%%~A"
  REM break the command into 2 parts, discarding port:
  REM %%B = before port
  REM %%E = after port
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%B in ("!cmd:port:=,!") do (
    for /f "tokens=1*" %%D in ("%%C") do (
      set /a n+=1
      REM transfer !n! into %%N
      for %%N in (!n!) do (
        REM build the new line
        set "ln=!ln!,%%B port:!port%%N! %%E"
      )
    )
  )
)

::remove space before comma
set "ln=!ln: ,=,!"

::write the result back to textfile2
>"textfile2.txt" echo !ln:~1!
```

Comment: Hey Dave, do you really want to use `THEN` word in `IF` command? Are you thinking on Pascal? :)

Comment: @Aacini - Thanks, every now and then I have a brain fart like that :-(  All fixed. I actually tested the code and it worked, but I never tested the empty file condition. The parser sees THEN as valid syntax. Only if TRUE does an error occur - *"'then' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below works with an unlimited list of servers in both text files and allows the `port:nnnn` option be included at any place in the line. It does not check for any errors to made it simpler.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Read data from both files
set /P "data1=" < textfile1.txt
set /P "data2=" < textfile2.txt
rem Replace "port" data in all servers
:nextServer
   rem Get port number after "port:" in first data and eliminate it
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%data1:*port:=%") do set port1=%%a& set data1=%%b
   rem Replace port number in second data and change colon by semicolon
   for /F "tokens=1  delims=," %%a in ("%data2:*port:=%") do set data2=!data2::%%a=;%port1%!
rem Pass to next server, if any
if defined data1 goto nextServer
rem Output result restoring colons
echo %data2:;=:%
```

For example, with this data:

```
  server1.net 2100 /l /n /k port:2000,server2.net 2100 /l /n /k port:20000,server5.net 2100 /l /n /k port:1234

server3.net 2000 /l /k port:xxxx,server4.net 2000 /l /k port:yyyyy,server6.net 2000 /l /k port:zzzz
```

The output is:

```
server3.net 2000 /l /k port:2000,server4.net 2000 /l /k port:20000,server6.net 2000 /l /k port:1234
```

Comment: That is elegant Aacini. But there are a few potential problems. The wrong port is extracted if there are additional options after `port:nnn` in data1 or data2, though that can be fixed by `"delims=, "`. All hell breaks loose if data1 is missing `port:`. Your manipulation of data2 is incorrect if two commands in data2 share the same initial `port:nnn`.

Answer (score 0):

A little more clarification on what you're looking to do in the long-term may help, but in the meantime, here is a script I just wrote and tested and it does exactly what you're asking.

```
for /f "tokens=6,12 delims=, " %%a in (textfile1.txt)do (
set portOne=%%a
set portTwo=%%b
call :writeTextTwo
)
type texttwo_temp>textfile2.txt
goto :EOF
:writeTextTwo
for /f "tokens=1-12 delims=, " %%c in (textfile2.txt)do (echo %%c %%d %%e %%f %portOne%,%%h %%i %%j %%k %portTwo% >>texttwo_temp )
 goto :EOF
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: However, this approach will not work if you have a long list of servers in both text files. If this is the case, it would be a lot easier just to import both text files into two excel documents, and separate the text into separate columns using the wizard (use space as the delims) and then just replace column 6 and column 11 from textfile2.txt with textfile1.txt)